# How to pass value of chosen input to eventListener function

Tags: javascript, html

I'm brand new to JavaScript, trying to add a simple event listener, to console.log a chosen color value from an input that the script appends to a div on page-load.

HTML:

```html
<html>
  <div id="myDiv">
  </div>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```js
/* First add an input color selector as a child of #myDiv 
with a datalist of available colors */
document.querySelector("#myDiv").innerHTML += `
  <input id="myInput" type="color" list="presetColors" 
       colorpick-eyedropper-active="false">

  <datalist id="presetColors">
    <option>#0275d8</option>
    <option>#5cb85c</option>
  </datalist>
`;

/* Trying to console.log the color value 
that was chosen in the input */
function myFunction(event) {
  console.log(event.value);
}

/* Adding an event listener so that when the color 
in the input changes, the function is called */
document
  .querySelector("#myInput")
  .addEventListener("change", myFunction(e));
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mccarthysean/0xvjcpLm/31/) to play with.

I don't understand the error message `"<a class='gotoLine' href='#62:1'>62:1</a> ReferenceError: e is not defined"`

I mean, it says [here on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Not_defined):

> The JavaScript exception "variable is not defined" occurs when there
> is a non-existent variable referenced somewhere.

*So how to I pass the value of the input to the function?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

First, when you specify the even handler here:

```
.addEventListener("change", myFunction(e));
```

You do not need to specify the parameters. In fact, you are not even calling the `myFunction` function at this point at all. You are just telling the listener which function is responsible for handling the event. You simply need to write:

```
.addEventListener("change", myFunction);
```

The event listener is what passes the "event" object after the event is actually fired.

Second, in `myFunction`, you need to access the value in one of two ways:

```
console.log(event.currentTarget.value);
```

or

```
console.log(this.value);
```

Answer (score 1):

In eventListener declarations, javascript expects either just the function name or an anonymous function. `.addEventListener("change", myFunction(e));` is not valid. In addition, you should use the full `myFunction(event)` rather than just `myFunction(e)`. Instead you should do:

```js
document
  .querySelector("#myInput")
  .addEventListener("change", () => myFunction(event));
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this [doc for "The event listener callback"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#The_event_listener_callback). The `listener` should be a callback function with the `event` as first parameter, you could explicitly call that

```
addEventListener("change", event => myFunction(event));
```

or just pass the function, as you implemented above

```
addEventListener("change", myFunction);
```

```js
/* First add an input color selector as a child of #myDiv 
with a datalist of available colors */
document.querySelector("#myDiv").innerHTML += `
  <input id="myInput" type="color" list="presetColors" 
       colorpick-eyedropper-active="false">

  <datalist id="presetColors">
    <option value="#0275d8">#0275d8</option>
    <option value="#5cb85c">#5cb85c</option>
  </datalist>
`;

/* Trying to console.log the color value 
that was chosen in the input */
function myFunction(event) {
  console.log(event.target.value);
}

/* Adding an event listener so that when the color 
in the input changes, the function is called */
document
  .querySelector("#myInput")
  .addEventListener("change", event => myFunction(event));
```

```html
<html>
<div id="myDiv">
</div>

</html>
```

Moreover, to get the value for `option`, you must specify each `option` with the `value` attribute, and grab it with `event.target.value`, rather than `event.value`

Comment: This returns undefined.

Comment: @norcaljohnny above previously was just to demonstrate to OP how he could get into `myFunction`

Answer (score 1):

A much more simple approach would be this.
Notice the oninput="console.log(this.value)"

You were also using queryselector improperly if you wanted to find it based on id the document.getElementById would have worked. Anyhow hope this helps.

```js
document.querySelector("div").innerHTML += `
  <input id="myInput" type="color" list="presetColors" colorpick-eyedropper-active="false" oninput="console.log(this.value)">
  <datalist id="presetColors" >
    <option>#0275d8</option>
    <option>#5cb85c</option>
  </datalist>
`;
```

```html
<div><div>
```